# Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/firebase/tubesock/WebSocket

Tags: java, firebase

I have the following error with the firebase-clint-jvm-2.3.0.jar
Class not found: com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket

```
Tue Jun 09 16:58:43 EDT 2015 [ERROR] RunLoop: Uncaught exception in Firebase runloop (2.3.0). Please report to support@firebase.com
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/firebase/tubesock/WebSocket
    at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection.createConnection(WebsocketConnection.java:164)
    at com.firebase.client.realtime.WebsocketConnection.<init>(WebsocketConnection.java:157)
    at com.firebase.client.realtime.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:60)
    at com.firebase.client.core.PersistentConnection.establishConnection(PersistentConnection.java:287)
    at com.firebase.client.core.Repo.deferredInitialization(Repo.java:81)
    at com.firebase.client.core.Repo.access$000(Repo.java:20)
    at com.firebase.client.core.Repo$1.run(Repo.java:70)
    at com.firebase.client.utilities.DefaultRunLoop$1.run(DefaultRunLoop.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.firebase.tubesock.WebSocket
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: Hi Jean-Baptiste. You're missing a jar or a part of a jar. How did you include Firebase in your project? Did you download the jar? Or are you using Maven? If the latter, can you show the relevant part of your pom file?

Comment: I used the jar. I try with Maven and it works. Thanks

Comment: Interesting. The jar is supposed to include tubesock. But anyway: yay, you got it working! :-)